# Craft CMS WYSIWYG Editor Issues

Tags: craftcms

I am using Craft CMS and just getting used to it. Seems like a great CMS, but I do have a question:

Whenever I add any of the WYSIWYG editors to Craft, all of them have an "Available Volumes" option for picking images. Mine is always empty, regardless of which WYSIWYG editor I try. IE, it says "Available Volumes" but there are no volume options to choose.

I am using Craft CMS 4. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have not created any asset volumes yet. Any you do create would be available as options in the RTE.

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/assets.html#volumes